# Getter in object isn't returning a value Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with return a value from an object.
my object looks like this.

> ```
>    function XYZ(date, startT)
>      {
>      var _date=date;
>      var _startT=startT;
>      this.get_date = function() {
>        return _date;
>        };
>       this.set_date = function(value) {
>         _date=value;
>       };
>        this.get_startT = function() {
>        return _startT;
>        };
>        this.set_startT = function(value) {
>        _startT=value;
>       };
>       this.toString()
>       return (_date + " " _startT);
>       }
> ```

then i create an Array like this

> ```
>    jsData[0] =new XYZ("2012-11-11","8:00");
>    jsData[1] = new XYZ("2012-03-03","8:00");
> ```

when i want to use get_date method it didn't return me the value but the get_startT method works fine. 
When i show object with .toString method it also show me full object

Please help.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding underscores in variable names. Concatenate names like this instead: `longVariableName`.

Comment: That code has a series of syntax errors, as your JavaScript engine should be showing you (in the console, on browser). Missing `{`, expressions started but never completed. The `this.toString()` would be a no-op if it had a semicolon after it (without the semicolon it causes a syntax error because of what follows it). Returning a string primitive out of a constructor function is another no-op.

Comment: i had {} in my code i was just missing () when i called this method
alert(jsData[2].get_date();

Comment: When you say "when I show object with .toString method" - if you define .toString as a method (see my answer below) it should work. Also make sure you actually call "jsData[0].toString()" - if you just refer to "jsData.toString" you'll see the function itself, not its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you fix all the syntax errors:

```
function XYZ(date, startT) {
  var _date=date;
  var _startT=startT;
  this.get_date = function() {
    return _date;
  };
  this.set_date = function(value) {
    _date=value;
  };
  this.get_startT = function() {
    return _startT;
  };
  this.set_startT = function(value) {
    _startT=value;
  };
}

var jsData = [];
jsData[0] = new XYZ("2012-11-11","8:00");
jsData[1] = new XYZ("2012-03-03","8:00");

display("jsData[0].get_date() = " + jsData[0].get_date());
```

Output:

```
jsData[0].get_date() = 2012-11-11
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/etetuy/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/etetuy/1/edit)

Other than obvious typos, here's what I did:

- Put `{` and `}` around the function body.
- Removed the `this.toString()` which was non-functional (a no-op, as you didn't store the result anywhere).
- Removed the return at the end, because returning a string primitive out of a constructor function is another no-op.
- Declared `jsData`.
- Initialized `jsData`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a opening bracket `{` after

```
function XYZ(date, startT)
```

And one at the end of your code. (`}`)

Comment: sorry, i was just typing fast and forgot..but that's not the point of whole story

Comment: @PawełBoruń: When posting code asking people to spend their time helping you, take the time to check that you've posted correct code. (Or better yet, use copy-and-paste -- because you *do* try to simplify things and run the simplified version before you post, right?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder mea culpa...i didn't want to copy so many lines, just the main source of problem. Thank for help :)

Comment: @PawełBoruń: Right, so you create a minimal, correct example, *try it*, and if it still has the issue you post the question with that minimal, correct example. Blindly posting half-edited code is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But what is interesting I'm calling get_startT method like this 
        jsData[i].get_startT
and it worked fine

Comment: @bohunn: Not with the code you originally posted it didn't. Nor indeed with the code in the question right now. If you fix the ***latest*** syntax error in that code (missing `+` in the `return` line), both `get_startT` **and** `get_date` work: http://jsbin.com/edelor/1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding methods to the function prototype like this:

```
function XYZ(date, startT) {
  this._date = date;
  this._startT = startT;
}

XYZ.prototype.get_date = function() {
  return this._date;
}
XYZ.prototype.set_date = function(value) {
  this._date = value;
}
XYZ.prototype.get_startT = function() {
  return this._startT;
}
XYZ.prototype.set_startT = function(value) {
  this._startT = value;
}
XYZ.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this._date + " " + this._startT;
}

var myXYZ = new XYZ("2012-11-11","8:00");
myXYZ.toString(); // "2012-11-11 8:00"
```

I tested that in the console and it outputs the final string correctly.

Comment: I would suggest against using it this way. You generally want your (pseudo-)class's functions to be defined within the class itself.

Comment: You're fundamentally changing his code (making the properties public), not explaining why what he posted isn't working.

Comment: Fair enough. In defence of my method, I believe inheriting prototype methods will perform better, but that's probably not an issue here (nor part of the question). I guessed (despite the broken syntax in the example given) that toString was meant to be a method definition, rather than a return from the constructor.

Comment: *"I believe inheriting prototype methods will perform better"* What makes you think that? Each call to them will require extra overhead, because for `myXYZ.get_date()`, the engine first has to do a lookup on the `myXYZ` object to see if it has a `get_date` property, and then seeing that it doesn't, repeat the lookup on its prototype. In contrast, if the function is assigned directly to the instance (as in the OP's code), the lookup doesn't have to be repeated. *(continued)*

Comment: *(continuing)* Now, if there are thousands of these `XYZ` objects, the fact that thousands of function objects are being created (because new functions have to be created to be assigned to the instances) could be an issue. But note that it's only the function *objects* that have to be recreated, a modern engine can reuse the underlying code (just with a different bound execution context).